# .NET Couchbase client slitent error connecting to Couchbase server

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2, client-server, couchbase

I have two servers. One of them acts as a client connecting to a couchbase server using the .NET client. The other is a configured couchbase server. These servers are hosted in Amazon EC2. For now I have opened all the ports on the couchbase server. However, when I try to connect using the .NET client the initialization code hangs and throws no errors. It also allows me to save and get with no errors except that the get always return null. I have verified that the IP and ports are reachable and opened.

Here is the code that I am trying.

```
CouchbaseClient = new CouchbaseClient("api_cache",""); //hangs for about 10 seconds throws no error
CouchbaseClient.Store(StoreMode.Set, "test","test")); //throws no error;
var test = CouchbaseClient.Get("test"); //always returns null;
```

This is the code in my web.config

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="couchbase" type="Couchbase.Configuration.CouchbaseClientSection, Couchbase" />

    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>

  </appSettings>
  <couchbase>
    <servers>
      <add uri="http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8091/pools" />
    </servers>
  </couchbase>
```

....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was basically a port blocking issue. For my use I needed to open the direct port.

I downloaded the .NET client source code and found references to the following ports:

- SsLPort: 11207
- ApiPort: 8092
- Management Port: 8091
- Direct Port:11210
- https Management Port: 18091
- https Api Port: 18092

I posted the answer to this on the Couchbase community as well.
http://www.couchbase.com/communities/q-and-a/i-cannot-connect-couchbase-server-amazon-ec2

Comment: Thanks @CodeMilian for posting back to the Couchbase community too